# Streamlit session_state and execution model

Tags: python, streamlit

```
import streamlit as st

st.title('Counter Example')
if 'count' not in st.session_state:
    print(f'initializing count!')
    st.session_state.count = 0
increment = st.button('Increment')
if increment:
    st.session_state.count += 1
    st.write('Count = ', st.session_state.count)
```

In the above code, I would expect to see the print statement 'initializing count!' only once. But I see it many times in a single execution run with only one active tab. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score -1):

In your code the Streamlit reruns the script every time there is a change in the widget state. This means that every time you click the 'Increment' button, Streamlit will rerun the script from top to bottom, and the 'count' variable will be initialized again.

```py
import streamlit as st

st.title('Counter Example')
if 'count' not in st.session_state:
    print(f'initializing count!')
    st.session_state.count = 0
    st.session_state.count_initialized = True
elif not st.session_state.count_initialized:
    print(f'count already initialized!')
    st.session_state.count_initialized = True

increment = st.button('Increment')
if increment:
    st.session_state.count += 1
    st.write('Count = ', st.session_state.count)
```

By using the st.session_state.count_initialized flag, the print statement will only execute once during the app's lifetime

Comment: Wait, what?  That's exactly what I'm doing.  Our code is identical.

Comment: @AmirAfghani apologies for the mistake ... really sorry. I have edited my answer now it will work

Comment: Your answer is not helpful.

Comment: And it looks to quite possibly be AI generated as well.